# Let $I \subset \mathbb R$ be a segment and let $f:I\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ be a monotonic function. Then $f$ is continuous if $f(I)$ is an interval

Tags: limits, continuity, monotone-functions

I am trying to prove the sentence:

> Let $I \subset\mathbb R$ be a segment (not necessarily closed and not necessarily bounded) and let $f: I \longrightarrow\mathbb R$ be a monotonic function. Then $f$ is continuous if and only if $f(I)$ is an interval.
> I was able to prove one direction — if $f(I)$ an interval then $f$ is continuous.

Here is my proof:

Suppose $f$ is monotonically ascending (otherwise we will look at $-f$).

We will deal with a case where $x_0$ is an internal point of $I$.

Holds: $K = \lim{x \to x_0^-} f (x) \le f (x_0) \le \lim_{x \to x_0^+} f (x) = L$, when at least one of the two inequalities is strict.

For example $K <f(x_0)$ then denote $A=\{f(x)\,|\,x\in I \wedge x<x_0\}$,

From $K =\sup(A)$ it follows that $\operatorname{Im}(f) \subset (−\infty,K]∪[f(x_0),\infty)$

Now  $\operatorname{Im}(f)\cap(−\infty,K] =\emptyset$, because $x_0$ is an internal point of $I$ and also $f(x_0)∈\operatorname{Im}(f)\cap[f(x_0),\infty)=∅$

But $(K,f(x0)) ̸= \emptyset$ and $(K,f(x_0)) \cap \operatorname{Im}(f) = \emptyset$ because $K <f(x_0)$ therefore $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is not an interval, in contradiction to a given.

I don't know how to prove the other direction — if $f$ is continuous than $f(I)$ is an interval. (I would be happy for any help).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a jump (discontinuity) of $f$ then we immediately get that

$f(I)=(a,b)\bigcup (b+\delta ,c )$ (where a can be -$\infty$  and $c$

$+\infty)$ therefore $f(I)$ is not a segment. i.e. if $f$ is not

continuous the range is not a segment. i.e. if the range is a segment,

$f$ is continuous. Now we need to prove the other direction. i.e. if

$f$ is continuous then the range is a segment. We invoke a well known

result of topology which says that the image of a connected set (when

$f$ is continuous) is a connected set which in $\mathbb{R}$ is

equivalent with a segment. I am sure that for the second direction an

elementary proof can also be found.

Answer (score 0):

By 'segment', I presume that you mean an 'interval'. In that case, the non-empty connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are exactly the segments. Continuous maps preserve connectedness. $f(I)$ being non-empty and connected is hence a segment.